# A term for the ground the swimmer steps on coming out of the whatever water he was swimming in

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

The example of a self-made sentence:

> He had to make a couple of fast strokes to reach the underwater
>   ground to just feel sort of safe from a possible shark attack.

Not that I ask for editing, it's the request for the term for the ground the swimmer steps on coming out of the whatever water he was swimming in. A bottom, ground, bed, floor--what it is, disregarding a body of water

Comment: Ok, at the beach. Right. He had to execute a couple of fast strokes so his feet could reach/touch the sand. I'd point out that sharks are **always in the sea**, so a swimmer's feet would have to touch the sand or possibly rock...One would not say the ocean floor here. I share this with you as a body boarder and big time beach swimmer. I don't see how you can disregard the fact it has to be the sea. Aren't all sentences "self-made" i.e. written by ourselves?

Comment: We would say **sea floor** or **ocean floor** or **the bottom** rather than **underwater ground**. That's if he's swimming down so as not to be attacked from below. The swimmer leaves the ocean and walks up onto the **beach** or **the shore**. *He swam quickly to shore*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a phrase used in English for what I think you're describing, but it's a verb phrase rather than a noun. [***Touch bottom***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/touch_bottom) is used when a swimmer is in water shallow enough that their feet can reach solid ground while their head is still above the water. Here's a dictionary from Oxford Dictionaries, with some relevant examples:

> Reach the bottom of a body of water with one's feet or a pole.
>
> > Example sentences
> >     *‘My feet **touch bottom**… It's cold in the water, but I'm warm.’*
> >     . . .
> >     *‘He finally struggled close enough to shore so his feet could **touch bottom**, then he just stood there with the water lapping at his neck.’*
> >     . . .
> >     *‘Her feet **touched bottom** and she stood up slowly, revelling in the water flowing from her as she rose from the pool.’*

If you wanted to use this phrase in your sentence, you could say something like

> He had to make a couple of fast strokes *so his feet could **touch bottom***, to just feel sort of safe from a possible shark attack.

You could probably just say "so *he* could touch bottom", but using "his feet" clarifies that you don't mean that he swam down to the ocean floor (to be below the sharks, maybe).

Of course, to be *actually* safe from shark attack, your hero should really get all the way out of the water ([sharks can bite in very shallow water](https://www.voanews.com/a/us-shark-attacks-occurred-in-waist-deep-water/2822370.html)), which (from the ocean) means on the shore or beach.

---

Two notes: It is possible to say that someone "touched bottom" when they swim down or sink to the bottom of a body of water that is over their head, but this should be clear from context. Also, there's a different, figurative use of the same phrase to mean "go as low as you can" (it's definition 1.2 in the same ODO entry; more often phrased as "hit bottom" in the US). Again, this meaning should be clear from context.

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic way to say that someone left the deeper water and swam to the beach is

> He swam quickly **[to shore](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22swam%20to%20shore%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)**.

P.S. And having swum to shore, he's standing on **the shore** (the land along the edge of the sea, broadly construed) or on **the beach** (the sandy, rocky, shelly, and/or pebbly ground onto which the surf washes according to the tides).

Comment: Sure, he does swim quickly to shore. His feet and what they want to reach is what I ask. To the shore, he does swim, what's under his feet? +1 for the interest

Comment: @Rompey: Please see the P.S.

Answer (score 3):

I would say "the shallows"

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-shallows

```
The shallows in British
a shallow place in a body of water
"At dusk more fish come into the shallows."
"Thousands of little fish swim in the shallows"
```

> He had to make a couple of fast strokes to reach the ***shallows***
>   to just feel sort of safe from a possible shark attack.

Answer (score 2):

"To reach the sandbank" is the phrase here in Australia. It's a pretty common phrase, and is exactly what you describe.

I think you could also say "to reach the shallows".

Looking up "sandbank", it seems it is also known as a shoal, but that term is less familiar to me.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoal

Comment: "To reach the shallows"--upvote by all means,

Comment: A shark can still get him in the shallows. A sandbank and a shoal are out in the midst of the water, surrounded by water. They are not the beach.